Css min-height: fit-content does not work with resize
  <div class="h-fit w-fit min-h-fit min-w-fit resize overflow-hidden bg-gray-200">
            <div> Content goes here.</div>
            <div> Content goes here.</div>
            <div> Content goes here.</div>
            <div> Content goes here.</div>
            <div> Content goes here.</div>
        </div>

The above is a minimal example tested in firefox and edge.
Even though it uses tailwind i have tried with inline styles too.
min-w-fit (min-width: fit-content) works as expected but the equivalent for min height does not.

In order for that to work you need to set a static value like min-h-[200px], but you don't wanna do that, so a workaround would be:
Remove min-h-fit and after the element renders, get it's height using JS and set it as a static minimum height
<div id="parentElement" class="h-fit w-fit min-w-fit resize overflow-hidden bg-gray-200">
    <div> Content goes here.</div>
    <div> Content goes here.</div>
    <div> Content goes here.</div>
    <div> Content goes here.</div>
</div>

<script>
    const height = document.getElementById('parentElement').offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById('parentElement').style.minHeight = `${height}px`;
</script>


I still don't understand why fit doesn't work , probably an un-addressed bug, but this worked , thanks!

I don't think it is a bug. In this case, as linked in What does min-height: max-content mean? in cross-axis (here it is height) min-height:fit-content will resolve to min-height:0. That is also why min-width:fit-content is working.

The min-height: fit-content property in CSS is intended to make an element's minimum height just enough to fit its content. However, it may not work as expected when combined with certain other properties, such as resizing. If you encounter issues with min-height: fit-content when resizing an element.
You can read more about min height and fit content here and here.
